# Scaling Adobe Illustrator objects in Adobe InDesign. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: adobe-indesign, shapes, resize, file-placing

I placed in an Adobe Illustrator AI object I made into an Adobe InDesign document.  When I scale the whole image, the AI object doesn't scale with everything else.  Any ideas?

[image: ID image with AI objects scaled]

[image: ID image with AI objects not scaled]

Answer (score 2):

Assumptions: You are selecting everything, then just grabbing a corner handle and draging it, with or without depressing the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key.

Since the Illustrator graphics are *placed, linked, images* in InDesign, they must be in an *frame*. Unlike native InDesign objects, Image Frames do **not** scale the *content inside the frame* if you just click-drag a handle on the (default) Bounding Box - the *frame* scales, what is inside the frame does **not** scale.

If you want frame contents to scale *with* their frame, you need to use the **Free Transform Tool** in InDesign and *not* the bounding box. While they look similar, they are not. This is one area where their operations differ.

You can easily switch to the **Free Transform Tool** by merely tapping the <kbd>e</kbd> key on the keyboard.

It *is* possible to *force* frame contents to scale *with* their associated frame by depressing the <kbd>Command/Ctrl</kbd> key while scaling with the Bounding Box. But often if you have a selection of both native objects and image frames, using the Free Transform Tool is simply more reliable.

Comment: Oh, yes, I should have placed the illustrator objects using the frames tool.  But the Free Transform Tool, with everything grouped, is working.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Not very clear what the problem is, but try grouping the entire artwork in InDesign, and then **hold CTRL and SHIFT** while scaling the resulting group.

Comment: I hadn't grouped all of the objects together before, but it worked.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Even though it's not quite apparent what the issue is, you may try selecting all of the artwork in InDesign at once, holding down the CTRL and SHIFT keys while you scale the resultant group.